# How to get product zoom extensions to work in custom theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, module, extensions, ce-1.7.0.2

I worked with the default theme as base an am slowly implementing my own theme on top of it by overriding it (as is recommended).

Now, I'm currently trying to install extensions that change how product images are display (my customer wants a zoom functionality as is used on many shops).

I tried these extensions:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/moo-cloudzoom.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-product-image-zoom-featurezoom.html

I installed them via magento connect without problems and configured them under configuration. Neither shows up on the site. I made sure they're active and are active in the right scope.

I did not override any phtml files so far, only some xml and a lot of css.

I'm using Magento v. 1.7.0.2

I'd be grateful for some help!

Answer (score 1):

Copy extension's design files in your custom theme's design package.

```
app/design/frontend/default/[YOUR CUSTOM THEME]
skin/frontend/default/[YOUR CUSTOM THEME]
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to switch back to default theme? Does it works when you use default styles?
Check if all styles/js are loaded on product pages.

Comment: Okay I did switch back to the default theme and the extension did indeed take effect. I just can't figure out what the problem is. What file could I've overwritten that causes this? I tried deletimg everything from the app directory but that didn't help. Likewise deleting the skin stuff.

Comment: In many cases, it can be something missing in custom XML layouts used in your template. You can check catalog.xml in <catalog_product_view> section and compare it to default layout.